# sorting numbers in excel when number contains dash '-'

Tags: excel, sorting

I have some number in a column in excel like this:

```
201
202
208-1
210
```

when I sort this column, sorted column is like below:

```
201
202
210
208-1
```

How do I sort this column? I want the sorted column becomes like this:

```
201
202
208-1
210
```

or

```
210
208-1
202
201
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is a hidden column, say if your values listed above were in A2:A5, insert a column to the right and in B2 enter the formula below and copy this down to the other B cells:

```
=IFERROR(VALUE(LEFT(A2,FIND("-",A2)-1)),VALUE(A2))
```

or alternative suggested by @Gary'sStudent that handles values after the hyphen as well by converting to decimals:

```
=IFERROR(VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"-",".")),VALUE(A2))
```

This strips out the number up to the first hyphen. Select all of the values in the two columns, select sort and then sort by columnB. you can then right click on column B and select hide.

If you do not want to use hidden columns then I think your only option would be to write some VBA to do a custom sort procedure. You would then also need a way of triggering this such as a control in the spreadsheet or just a keyboard shortcut.

**UPDATE**

I have had a go at the VBA procedure, it was not as straight forward as I expected so it may be that there is an easier way to do this.

The basic steps I went through are to prompt the user for a cell range (you just have to select the cells when prompted), store the values to an array of strings, create an equivalent numeric array where the hyphens are replaced by decimal points, sort the numeric array and then loop through the initial range pasting in the values in order.

I was surprised to find out that VBA does not have a built in method for sorting an array, but found some code that could be used [here](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/SortingArrays.aspx). This creates a temp worksheet and uses the worksheet function, there is also code there for a pure VBA solution but it's pretty lengthy.

To create the VBA procedure you will need to open the VBA editor with alt F11 and create a new module then paste the code below into a module (create a new module - right click on modules on right and insert) then paste in the code below.

The procedure that you need to call is `sort_with-hyphens`.

You will need to create a control or create a keyboard short cut to trigger this. For either you will need to enable the developer ribbon tab through File>Options.  For the control do developer>control>button and right click to assign a macro. For the keyboard short cut developer>Macros select the VBA procedure name from the list of macros and select options.

```
Sub sort_with_hyphens()
On Error GoTo sort_with_hyphens_err
   Dim vRange As Range
   Dim vCell As Variant
   Dim vStrArray(), vNumArray()
   Dim i As Long, vStart As Long, vEnd As Long
   Dim vStep As String: vStep = "Initialising values"

   ' prompt user to specify range
   Set vRange = Application.InputBox("Select a range to be sorted", _
                                     "Obtain Range Object", _
                                     Type:=8)
   vStrArray = vRange.Value
   vStart = LBound(vStrArray)
   vEnd = UBound(vStrArray)
   ReDim vNumArray(vStart To vEnd)
   vStep = "Populating Numeric Array"

   ' loop through array copying strings with hyphen to decimal equivalent
   For i = vStart To vEnd
       vNumArray(i) = Val(Replace(vStrArray(i, 1), "-", "."))
       Debug.Print i, vNumArray(i)
   Next i

   ' sort numeric array
   vStep = "Sorting Numeric Array"
   SortViaWorksheet vNumArray

   ' write out sorted values
   vStep = "Writing out Sorted Values"
   For i = vStart To vEnd
       ' convert back to string and switch periods back to hyphens
       vRange.Cells(i, 1).Value = Replace(CStr(vNumArray(i)), ".", "-")
   Next

sort_with_hyphens_exit:
    Exit Sub

sort_with_hyphens_err:
    If vStep = "Writing out Sorted Values" Then
        MsgBox ("An error has occurred, the original values will " & _
                "be restored. Error in Step: " & vStep & vbCrLf & _
                "Error Details:" & vbCrLf & err.Number & " - " & _
                err.Description)
        For i = vStart To vEnd
            ' replace with original value incase of error
            vRange.Cells(i, 1).Value = vStrArray(i)
        Next
    Else
        MsgBox ("An error has occurred in Step: " & vStep & vbCrLf & _
                "Aborting sort procedure." & vbCrLf & _
                "Error Details:" & vbCrLf & err.Number & " - " & _
                err.Description)
   End If
End Sub

Sub SortViaWorksheet(pArray)
    Dim WS As Worksheet ' temporary worksheet
    Dim R As Range
    Dim N As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    ' create a new sheet
    Set WS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add

    ' put the array values on the worksheet
    Set R = WS.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(pArray) - LBound(pArray) + 1, 1)
    R = Application.Transpose(pArray)

    ' sort the range
    R.Sort key1:=R, order1:=xlAscending, MatchCase:=False

    ' load the worksheet values back into the array
    For N = 1 To R.Rows.Count
        pArray(N) = R(N, 1)
    Next N

    ' delete the temporary sheet
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    WS.Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    ' test/debug/confirmation
    Debug.Print vbCrLf & "Sorted Array:" & vbCrLf & "------------"
    For N = LBound(pArray) To UBound(pArray)
        Debug.Print N, pArray(N)
    Next N
End Sub
```

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: It is also worth noting that this solution would not be enough if you needed to order two or more values with the same numbers before the hyphen correctly e.g. if your example had `208-1` and `208-2`. To handle this scenario you would either need a custom sort procedure (as mentioned in the answer) or slightly more elaborate formula e.g. treating everything after the hyphen as a decimal).

Comment: can you give me a start point to write a custom sort procedure.

Comment: @ChrisProsser........another play is to substitute **.** for the **-** so as to convert the dash part into a decimal.....this will allow *108-1* and *108-2* to also be sorted correctly!

Comment: @Gary'sStudent Yeah, that's a smart solution, somewhat simpler than mine if done in the hidden column as well.

Comment: @mohammad I have updated my answer to include a VBA solution as well.